# Can I Prevent Git from Using XTerm Escape Sequences?

Tags: bash, git, matlab, ansi-escape, xterm

I am writing some code where MATLAB queries Git tags:

```matlab
[status, cmdout] = system("TERM=xterm; git tag -l")
```

On my Windows 11 partition, where I wrote the code in the first place, this works fine, I get a newline-separated list of tags. On my Ubuntu partition, however, the command output is

```
'[?1h=
     mytag[m
     
     [K[?1l>'
```

(`mytag` is the only tag present. On W11, the output was just `mytag`)
which, decoded, is apparently

```
'\x1B[?1h\x1B=\x13mytag\x1B[m\x13\x10\x13\x1B[K\x1B[?1l\x1B>'
```

or

```
'<ESC>[?1h<ESC>=\rmytag<ESC>[m\r\n\r<ESC>[K<ESC>[?1l<ESC>>'
```

I've found out that these `<ESC>[...` sequences are escape sequences for formatting and text color. Most of them are ANSI escape sequences, however it seems that `<ESC>=` and `<ESC>>` are XTerm-specific.

I thought at first that it was a difference in how `bash` and `cmd` return their output to MATLAB*, but I tested this by making my own program that prints "hello, world" with colored writing and calling it from MATLAB in both OSes, and the ANSI sequences show up literally on Windows, too. So it looks like it's Git that is behaving differently, although it *could* be something else.

I've started working on a Regex to just strip all of these out, but all those carriage returns that Git inserted break a bunch of my code (it uses numerous Git commands. Don't ask why), and I think I'll end up creating some very brittle and ugly code unless I figure out how to make Git just print out the same plain output as it does on Windows.
If I don't prefix my Git command with `TERM=xterm`, the default terminal mode is `dumb`, which you'd *think* is exactly what I want. However, if you do this, Git prints out a warning

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
Press RETURN to continue
```

and it doesn't look like the MATLAB `system` command can be used to answer this prompt, also the prompt only occurs on some commands, and finally Git still includes one ANSI sequence (and those damned line breaks) in the `git tag -l` output even when I use dumb mode, so it's useless anyway.

So - is it possible to prevent Git from printing out anything except plain text, but without requiring manual confirmation on some commands? Why did all of this work so easily on Windows - is Git even at fault?
Any explanation on why I even get the different behavior between Ubuntu and Windows at all, better approaches to solve this, or whatever might help, are very welcome.

* that is how it works, right? `system` starts a `bash`/`cmd` process, feeds it the command string, and then collects its output?

Comment: Don't use a semicolunm: `system("TERM=xterm git tag -l")`! And try:  `system("TERM=none git tag -l")`

Comment: Thanks, but `TERM=none` produces the same result as `TERM=dumb`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MATLAB is setting up commands to run on a pty, you can make Git *not* talk to a pty with `git tag -l | cat`. Then you don't have to care about the terminal type.

You could also eliminate the human-convenience transform by using a core command, not a convenience one: `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)'  refs/tags`, core commands are built for scriptable and reliable output.

Comment: I also considered `git tag -l | cat` but when OP said that `git tag -l --no-color` isn't enough (there are no color escape codes in the output) I doubt that that, or the `for-each-ref` version, will work.  It seems to be the prompt that is the issue.

Comment: What's the point of doubt when it's so easy to check?

Comment: I have no way of checking unfortunately. Have you checked that it works on Ubuntu if you have a colorized prompt?

Comment: Those both produce `mytag\n` as output, which is what I was going for. I think I'll use the core command, seems cleaner. I've found numerous flaws in my approach with `git tag` so far, and this is the last straw. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, another question, actually: how do I find out whether something is a core or convenience command? The [help page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) for git tag doesn't mention that `git tag -l` is built on `for-each-ref`, and a Google search for "git core command" just brings up a bunch of  "most important Git commands you should know" listicles.

Comment: Think I found it: the commands listed under "plumbing commands" [here](https://git-scm.com/docs) are the internal ones.

Comment: @LemongrabThree That's the one. I should have mentioned that, sorry. The plumbing/core commands are built specifically for scripting, and in fact many of te "porcelain"/convenience commands started and could still be implemented as scripts. Another thing you might try if you're in the mood to just poke at it to see stuff is `git --no-pager tag -l`, that's another way to shut off the pager invocation `git tag` does, and I think it's the pager the convenience aka porcelain commands invoke doing what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `--no-color` option as it's the portable, shell-independent, way to turn off coloring. You can combine that with setting environment variables, like `TERM`, in the MATLAB [`system`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command.

```
[status, cmdout] = system("git tag -l --no-color", "TERM", "dumb")
```

Or set the prompt to something without escape sequences if it's the prompt that causes the problems. This will only affect shells like [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) that uses `PS1` for the prompt:

```
[status, cmdout] = system("git tag -l --no-color", "PS1", "mytag",
                                                   "PROMPT_COMMAND","")
```

Other options for git:

1. Turn off the specific coloring you don't want. Here are a few:

   ```
   git -c color.ui -c color.branch \
       -c color.diff -c color.interactive -c color.status git-command
   ```

   E.g., `color.ui` here means the same as `color.ui=false`, but with less typing.
2. Turn off coloring globally by changing your `~/.gitconfig`. This will however affect your normal interactive shells too. Here are all options as of git v2.43.0:

   ```
   [color]
       advice = false
       branch = false
       diff = false
       grep = false
       interactive = false
       pager = false
       push = false
       remote = false
       status = false
       transport = false
       ui = false
   ```

Comment: The example I posted doesn't have any color escapes, only formatting ones, and those are all still present when you turn off coloring.

Comment: @LemongrabThree I see. I added an option for setting the prompt to the answer.